# How to stop typing characters in textfield when text is the same size as textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to find a way where when the characters completely fill up a textfield, to let the user type but it doesn't add any new characters to the textfield (like Snapchat). I've only see this done in Objective-C and I wasn't able to translate it into Swift. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you want to limit the number of characters in a textfield? Can you post the objective c code for which you want a swift equivalent?

Comment: @UsamaArshad Sorry I just got back. But Rashwan Lazkani answered my question. But thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
@IBAction func textField_EditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
            //Set your font and add attributes if needed.
            let stringSize: CGSize = textField!.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: textField.font!])

            if (stringSize.width > textField.bounds.width - 20){
                textField.deleteBackward()
            }
    }
```

I added - 20 since I wanted to be sure that no small chars is added like "i", "1" etc.

Comment: Thank you! You're a life saver.